# Syntax error in linker script

Tags: gcc, assembly, linker, linker-errors, linker-scripts

I have a syntax error on line 8
I have read the [GNU docs](http://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/ld_3.html) concerning the syntax and managed to solve the syntax error but got incompatibility issues
Here's my script:

```
ENTRY (loader)
OUTPUT ("kernel.bin")

addr = 0x100000;
SECTIONS
{
        .text addr: 
        ALIGN(0x1000)
        {
            *(.text*);
            *(.rodata*);
        }

        .data:
        ALIGN(0x1000)
        {
            *(.data*);
        }

        .bss:
        ALIGN(0x1000)
        {
            *(.bss*);
        }
}
```

Please excuse me as I'm just trying to startup with OSDeving with a Hello World sample

Comment: Can you add the error message you receive to your question?

Comment: @FUZxxl it simply says **ld:linker.ld:8: syntax error** 
Nothing that can help I guess

Comment: Can you try and remove `addr` after `.text`?

Comment: Now the error jumped to line 9! can't I refer to the addr I declared to pad bytes with the ALIGN command?

Comment: The problem is that `addr` is a symbol. I believe ld does not allow you to use symbols here because there would be too many complicated corner cases to implement. Consider using a `MEMORY` directive to declare sections of memory you can later refer to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what my linker script looked like before I moved my kernel to the higher half:

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT("elf32-i386","elf32-i386","elf32-i386")
OUTPUT_ARCH(i386)

ENTRY(entry)
SECTIONS
{
    . = 0x00100000;
    start = .;
    .text : 
    {
        *(.text)
        . = ALIGN(4096);
    }

    .data :
    {
        *(.data)
        *(.rodata)
        . = ALIGN(4096);
    }

    .bss :
    {
        *(.bss)
        *(stack_bottom)
        *(stack_top)
        . = ALIGN(4096);
    }
    end = .;
    kernel_end = .;
}
```

I believe the issue is lack of space between ".text" and the colon. I had ld give me errors like that for a different project.
If you want to designate where each section should be located, do it like this:

```
.text : AT(ADDR(.text) - 0xC0000000)
    {
        *(.text)
        . = ALIGN(4096);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you ! This solved the syntax error but as I said earlier it brings up incompatibility error

Comment: Can you paste the error? I haven't seen an incompatibility error yet.

Comment: the error was **i386 architecture of input file 'build/loader.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output** and I managed to fix that by adding `-melf_i386` as an additional parameter to the linker command, now I'm booting my kernel properly ! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try to assign addresses to sections like this:

```
ENTRY (loader)
OUTPUT ("kernel.bin")

SECTIONS
{
        . = 0x100000;
        .text: 
        ALIGN(0x1000)
        {
            *(.text*);
            *(.rodata*);
        }

        .data:
        ALIGN(0x1000)
        {
            *(.data*);
        }

        .bss:
        ALIGN(0x1000)
        {
            *(.bss*);
        }
}
```